# React - .map returning not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was following this example: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

But my code is returning weather.map is not a function?

```
function App(props) {

  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=kalamazoo&appid=XXXXXXXXXXXX")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
      setWeather(result)
      console.log(result)
      }
    )
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {weather.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>{item.main}</li>
      ))}
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I understand that it expects an array, but even if the API hasn't returned I still get the error.

Comment: I think the data you're getting from api is not of array type. What data did you get in console.log?

Comment: I think weather API returns an object

Answer (score 2):

The openweathermap GET /weather API returns an object. You can check out on their [Swagger](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/IdRatherBeWriting/open-weather_map_api/2.5.2#/Current%20Weather%20Data/CurrentWeatherData) for details of the APIs and their exact response formats

To access the weather information, you need to do the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=kalamazoo&appid=XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
            setWeather(result.weather); // this is where weather data array is present
            console.log(result);
        });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

map is not a function error mean that that `weather` data type is not an array so it hasn't a map function
the API returning an Object so instead of direct map you can use

```
Object.values(weather || {}).map((item)=>{
  return(
   <li key={item.id}>{item.main}</li>
 )
})
```